# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Im getting the following error when trying to update values in my db.

`sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.`

This is my model:

```
class AddProduct(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Numeric(10,2), nullable=False)
    stock = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    discount = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=0)
    color = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)
```

And this is my form:

```
class AddProducts(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.DataRequired()])
    price = DecimalField('Price', [validators.DataRequired()])
    discount = DecimalField('Discount', default=0)
    stock = DecimalField('Stock', [validators.DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', [validators.DataRequired()])
    color = TextAreaField('Colours', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

This is my html:

```
                        <h2 class="text-center"> Add Product</h2>
                        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field  %}
                        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ render_field(form.name, class="form-control", placeholder="Please enter product name")}}
                        {{ render_field(form.price, class="form-control", placeholder="Please enter product price")}}
                        {{ render_field(form.discount, class="form-control", placeholder="Please enter product discount")}}
                        {{ render_field(form.stock, class="form-control", placeholder="Please enter product stock")}}
```

This is the full error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: UPDATE add_product SET name=?, price=?, stock=?, discount=?, brand_id=?, category_id=? WHERE add_product.id = ?]
[parameters: ('ihpone', 5000.0, Decimal('6'), None, '1', [<Category 1>, <Category 2>, <Category 3>, <Category 4>], 2)]
```

I have no issues when creating the objects initially but when I try to update them I get the above error.

Comment: I changed this but im still getting the same error.

Comment: `stock` is `None`, but the database will not accept a `NULL` value.